# How to get the certificate's signature key length using python ssl module

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, openssl, tls1.2

In python ssl module, I can create a TLS connection using this code snippet:

```
import socket, ssl

context = ssl.SSLContext()
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
context.check_hostname = True
context.load_default_certs()

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ssl_sock = context.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname='www.verisign.com')
ssl_sock.connect(('www.verisign.com', 443))
```

I also can get the perr's certificate using the `getpeercert` function which returns an object with the certificate's info as this:

```
{'issuer': ((('countryName', 'IL'),),
            (('organizationName', 'StartCom Ltd.'),),
            (('organizationalUnitName',
              'Secure Digital Certificate Signing'),),
            (('commonName',
              'StartCom Class 2 Primary Intermediate Server CA'),)),
 'notAfter': 'Nov 22 08:15:19 2013 GMT',
 'notBefore': 'Nov 21 03:09:52 2011 GMT',
 'serialNumber': '95F0',
 'subject': ((('description', '571208-SLe257oHY9fVQ07Z'),),
             (('countryName', 'US'),),
             (('stateOrProvinceName', 'California'),),
             (('localityName', 'San Francisco'),),
             (('organizationName', 'Electronic Frontier Foundation, Inc.'),),
             (('commonName', '*.eff.org'),),
             (('emailAddress', 'hostmaster@eff.org'),)),
 'subjectAltName': (('DNS', '*.eff.org'), ('DNS', 'eff.org')),
 'version': 3}
```

I need to extract the certificate's Public-Key type and length (e.g. RSA 2048-bit). How can I get this info?

Answer (score 1):

Run `getpeercert(True)` to fetch the binary DER format of the full certificate, then with the OpenSSL crypto library you can get the key type and length this way (assume `der` is the binary DER):

```py
import OpenSSL

certificate = OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_ASN1, der)
public_key = certificate.get_pubkey()
key_type = 'RSA' if public_key().type() == OpenSSL.crypto.TYPE_RSA else 'DSA'
key_length = public_key.bits()
```